# Why does PRIx64 print "lx" instead of 16 hex chars?

Tags: c, hex, 32-bit, cortex-m, uint64

We've run into an issue at work where we were not able to use the "portable" types from `<inttypes.h>` (PRIx64) to correctly print a 64-bit unsigned integer in hexadecimal format.

```
uint64_t serial = 0x12345678;
usb_printf("Serial: %"PRIx64"\n", serial);
```

where

```
void usb_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char string[512];
    uint16_t string_length = 0;
    va_list va;

    va_start(va, fmt);
    string_length = vsnprintf(string, ARRAY_SIZE(string), fmt, va);
    bsp_usb_cdc_send_buf((uint8_t *)string, string_length);
    va_end(va);
}
```

gives

```
> Serial: lx
```

This is running on a LPC55S28 (Cortex-M33), and linked with `-specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs` using GCC.

By looking at PRIx64 definition, it seems that it was defined as:

```
#define __INT64 "ll"
#define __PRI64(x) __INT64 __STRINGIFY(x)
#define PRIx64      __PRI64(x)
```

Why isn't the `PRIx64` portable type definition behaving as one would expect on this platform?

Comment: Try `printf("%llx\n", 1LLU)`... I mean: you may have a library issue, not a compiler issue

Comment: And what does the output of the preprocessor look like?  Can you just *compile* the source code with `gcc -E ...` and see what it's expanded into?

Comment: Maybe you can print in 32-bit chunks? `usb_printf("Serial: %"PRIx32"%08"PRIx32"\n", serial>>32, (uint32_t)serial);`

Answer (score 5):

newlib-nano does not support float numbers (you need to tell the linker to link the support) and `printf` does not support `long long` numbers (and there is no way to add the support).

You must not use `nano.specs` if you want to printf `long long` numbers

Nano documentation explicitly says that

```
     enable-newlib-io-pos-args
     enable-newlib-io-c99-formats
     enable-newlib-io-long-long
     enable-newlib-io-long-double
```

build options are not supported. So even rebuilding the library with those options will not add the support.

Conclusion:

1. Do not use newlib-nano
2. Write your own `long long` print functions.

General remark: when you program micro-controllers you should forget many things you normally use when programming big machines (like PC computers), especially `malloc` style allocations and fancy `printf` formats.

Comment: Could you point me to newlib-nano's documentation? I could only find the newlib documentation. I can see that it has to be enabled for newlib, but I can't find whether nano supports it or not.